# Garbage collection of private fields

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Given the code below.

```
class A {
    private B b;
    public A() {
        b = new B();
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(); // two objects are created (a and b)
        // <-- is B object, referenced only by private a.b eligible for garbage collection?
        keepAlive(a);
    }
}
```

Can B object be garbage collected after the A object is created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think no, because this field still can be accessed via reflection (using `setAccessible(true)`).

Theoretically, compiler can prove that this field would never be accessed, and it would make `B` eligible for garbage collection (from [JLS 12.6.1 Implementing Finalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#12.6.1)):

> A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread. Optimizing transformations of a program can be designed that reduce the number of objects that are reachable to be less than those which would naively be considered reachable. For example, a compiler or code generator may choose to set a variable or parameter that will no longer be used to null to cause the storage for such an object to be potentially reclaimable sooner.

But I don't think that in practice compilers and JVMs are that smart

Answer (score 1):

@Kuba Do you mean: can the instance of class `B` in the field `b` of instance `a` of class `A` be garbage collected? No. Not while `a` is not `null` as the `b` is referenced by `a`.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the main thread has a path to `b` through `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard compiler is not that smart.

```
class A
{
    private Object[] array;

    public A()
    {
        array = new Object[10000000];
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LinkedList<A> list = new LinkedList<A>();
    while (true)
    {
        list.add(new A());
    }
}
```

This code throws out of memory exception after a very small number of loops, so the answer to the original question is definitely no.